# missing right parenthesis error in add constraint

Tags: sql, oracle

```sql
alter table jdetails add constraint check_fee check (fee in('PAID','PENDING');
```

> alter table jdetails add constraint check_fee check (fee in('PAID','PENDING')
>
> ERROR at line 1:
>
> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

what is the mistake in my add constraint..?
please tell me...any one

Comment: should be: alter table jdetails add constraint check_fee check (fee in('PAID','PENDING'))

Comment: Count the `(`'s and `)`'s. Same number?

Answer (score 2):

just add one more parenthesis `)` to your statement in check. your check function is not closed

Comment: Can you please accept it as an answer if it works for you

Comment: alter table jdetails add constraint fk_f_id_jdetails foreign key(f_id) references naresh(f_id);                                                                       ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "F_ID": invalid identifier

Comment: Did you declare f_id varchar or does that table jdetails contains fid something that you are referring

Answer (score -1):

Always check that your parenthesis are closed, no matter what language. You were missing a parenthesis at the end that matched with the "check" function. The easiest way to quickly check is to either count the number of "left-parenthesis (" and see if they match the number of "right-parenthesis )". Also, depending on your IDE, when highlighting/clicking on a parenthesis, it may highlight its currently matching parenthesis.

```
alter table jdetails add constraint check_fee check (fee in('PAID','PENDING'));
```

Edit: Someone care to tell me why this was downvoted? Lol